# Error when trying to open C# Interactive window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, roslyn

I just installed the Roslyn CTP, but when I try to open the C# Interactive Window I got a popup error message:

> No valid exports were found that match the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Repl.IInteractiveWindowProvider") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Repl.IInteractiveWindowProvider".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))', invalid exports may have been rejected.

I am using visual studio 2010. I have reinstalled the Roslyn CTP, it still don't work.

Comment: Fixed by install the `Roslyn" Oct 2011 CTP` first.

Comment: You should post that as a answer, when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by install the `Roslyn Oct 2011 CTP` first.